# Выборка из многомерного массива PHP

Tags: php, массивы

Имеется массив:

```
[{"type":"deposit","currency":"ltc","amount":"0.0","available":"0.0"},
{"type":"deposit","currency":"usd","amount":"631.04896274","available":"0.000001"},
{"type":"exchange","currency":"btc","amount":"0.0","available":"0.0"},
{"type":"exchange","currency":"ltc","amount":"0.00002317","available":"0.00002317"},
{"type":"exchange","currency":"usd","amount":"0.0","available":"0.0"},
{"type":"trading","currency":"ltc","amount":"0.0","available":"0.0"},
{"type":"trading","currency":"usd","amount":"0.0","available":"0.0"}]
```

Не разобрался, как делать выборку сразу по нескольким ключам. Тупой перебор не хотелось бы =)

Требуется выбрать значение amount, где "type":"deposit","currency":"usd".
Переменная $result содержит массив выше.

```
for ($i = 0; $i <= (count($result)); $i++){
    foreach ($result[$i] as $key => $value) { //интерпретатор уже выплёвывает ошибку "Invalid argument supplied for foreach()"
        if ($key == "usd"){    // а здесь так и подмывает воткнуть ($key == "deposit")&&($key == "usd")
            echo ($key.": ".$value."<br>");
        }
    }
}
```

Обращаю внимание, что значения ключей в подмассивах могут повторяться.

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: И в чем же ваша проблема? Вообще, это похоже на JSON и работать с ним надо соответствующим образом.

Comment: Без проблем, можно работать как с json.

Comment: Так и работайте. В чем проблема - не понятно.

Comment: Не разобрался, как делать выборку сразу по нескольким ключам. Тупой перебор не хотелось бы =)

Comment: Почему же вы тогда не пишете этого сразу в вопросе?

Comment: Наверное, специально, чтобы вас порадовать.

Comment: А в итоге сообщество "порадует" вас за постановку задания в виде "требуется то-то и то-то, быстро и бесплатно".

Comment: Надеялся, что есть удобный способ сделать выборку из массива, нежели перебор, включая подмассивы...

Comment: Постарался откорректировать для большей ясности вопроса.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используя JSON

```
$t='[{"type":"deposit","currency":"ltc","amount":"0.0","available":"0.0"},
{"type":"deposit","currency":"usd","amount":"631.04896274","available":"0.000001"},
{"type":"exchange","currency":"btc","amount":"0.0","available":"0.0"},
{"type":"exchange","currency":"ltc","amount":"0.00002317","available":"0.00002317"},
{"type":"exchange","currency":"usd","amount":"0.0","available":"0.0"},
{"type":"trading","currency":"ltc","amount":"0.0","available":"0.0"},
{"type":"trading","currency":"usd","amount":"0.0","available":"0.0"}]';

$d=json_decode($t,true);


foreach ($d as $v){
    if ($v["type"]=="deposit" && $v["currency"]=="usd") echo $v["amount"]; echo "\n";

}
```

Проверка http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/a12b16aa231d34782e30522255cb67f9c7ae5bd7

Comment: Спасибо! Что забавно, JSON тут вы всё-равно декодируете в обычный массив =))) а мой косяк был в том, что **json_decode** я использовал без **true**

Answer (score 0):

Без перебора не обойтись, но можно уменьшить количество кода с помощью array_filter:

```
$filtered = array_filter($data, function($item){ 
  return $item['type'] === 'deposit' && $item['currency'] === 'usd';
});

var_dump(reset($filtered));
```

В Вашем же коде, нужно просто убрать лишний цикл и заменить `<=` на `<`:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < (count($result)); $i++) {
  $item = $result[$i];
  if ($item['type'] === 'deposit' && $item['currency'] === 'usd') {
    var_dump($item);
  }
}
```

Или проще с foreach:

```
foreach ($result as $item) {
  if ($item['type'] === 'deposit' && $item['currency'] === 'usd') {
    var_dump($item);
  }
}
```

---

Если Вам нужно многократно обращаться к этим данным, стоит предварительно перестроить структуру:

```
$data = [];
foreach ($result as $item) {
    $data[$item['type']][$item['currency']] = $item;
}

echo "Amount of usd deposit: {$data['deposit']['usd']['amount']}\n";
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Правда, в итоге, воспользовался вариантом выше =)